# 2 text box need to verify they are not empty or contain 0

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function with info that grabs hours, rates, and then tax deduction and then spits it out. It works fine

```
 var newtax= new Number(dep[i]);
 taxrate = newtax*100;
 var h=eval(document.paycheck.hours.value);
 var r=eval(document.paycheck.payrate.value);
 document.paycheck.feedback.value= taxrate + txt;
 var total= r*(1-newtax)*h ;
 total=total.toFixed(2);
 document.paycheck.feedback3.value= ("$ "+ total);
```

I have to put where it takes the total and puts it in a function to put it only two decimals. It works this way and only does two decimals but i need the decimal conversion in a function. can anyone shed some like .

This is where i cut it to two decimals and i am unable to put in function and then send it back to the feedback3.value.

```
 total=total.toFixed(2);
 document.paycheck.feedback3.value= ("$ "+ total);
```

Comment: is the document.paycheck.feedback object populating correctly? have you used an alert to verify that the total variable is as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to write a function that takes a number and formats it as a dollar value with two decimals (as a string) then this would work:

```
function formatMoney(num) {
   return "$ " + num.toFixed(2);
}

// which you could use like this:
document.paycheck.feedback3.value= formatMoney(total);

// though you don't need the total variable (unless you use it elsewhere)
// because the following will also work:
document.paycheck.feedback3.value = formatMoney( r*(1-newtax)*h );
```

By the way, you don't need `eval` to get the values from your fields. Just say:

```
var h = document.paycheck.hours.value;
var r = document.paycheck.payrate.value;
```